# Sharing different videos providers to Facebook using Wordpress

Tags: flash, facebook, video, facebook-like, share

I want to be able to share videos from my Wordpress site to Facebook using different video providers. I was able to use my own video player, but I'm not ready to post videos using my server and I prefer to have users post using a provider like youtube, vimeo, facebook, ect.... Right now my site has those kind of video players. I edit the meta tags several times, this is the one I currently have:

```
    <meta name=”medium” content=”medium_type” /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" /> 
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), 25); ?>" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="article" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://gullypost.com/wp-content/themes/gullypost/images/fbmov.jpg" /> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="145902762138730" /> 
<meta property="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> 
<meta property="video_height" content="360" /> 
<meta property="video_width" content="640" /> 

   <link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo $wpc_image_url[0] ?>"; } ?>" /> 

<link rel="videothumbnail" href="<?php if( ( $video_thumbnail = get_video_thumbnail() ) != null ) { echo "<img src='".$video_thumbnail."' />"; } ?>" /> 
  <!-- CALLIN A PLUGIN THAT DOES VIDEO THUMBNAILS, HOPING IT WILL WORK, THIS IS NOT MAKING IT SHOW UP ON MY WALL WITH THUMBNAIL FOR VIDEO --> 

  <link rel="video_src" href="<?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'videosource', true); ?>" /> <!-- THIS IS A CUSTOM POST WITH LINK OF SOURCE LIKE YOUTUBE OR VIMEO, BUT IS NOT MAKING IT SHOW UP ON MY WALL -->
```

I also tested it using a single youtube video and it worked fine. But since I have other videos beside youtube I can't do it where it just gets a youtube id. Yesterday the posts without videos were showing up, but now when all posts gets share it shows up like if it was a video on my wall, so if clicked it will give an error. I been pulling my hair all week with this and still couldn't get it to work. Can anybody point me out the problem, or tell me how I should do it. I search everywhere but they just explain the same thing, basically for one player. I'll appreciate it if you can help me out here.

Another thing is... when I update my script, it takes so long for facebook to update the change. I have to wait for so long in order to test it again, like if facebook is holding it in cache for too long, is there a way to bypass that?

Comment: hello - currently having loads of problems trying to share videos. Do i need to create an App for this? Not sure where people are getting a value for fb:app_id from? Dc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a video display, use the og:video meta tag instead of the `<link rel"video_src" />` code you are using now.  The value of the og:video tag should be a .swf file (or a youtube link which will get automatically converted).  You can see the open graph meta tags needed for video [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

You can get the cache updated by using the [URL Linter Debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out, at-least now i now about the URL Linter Debugger. I had tested the og:video before and it worked but since I wanted to be able to have different videos players I might have to do a few if statements and just call the id where it belongs :\ because i thought og:video was only for swf , thats the reason I used link rel"video_src" instead. Atleast I'm not getting error, i see it loading the swf but nothing shows, just plain white. I should be able figure it out. I also figure how to call the video thumbnail with just calling video_thumbnail(); i was doing it wrong.